# Java not removing specific item from list

Tags: java, minecraft

I am currently developing a plugin in minecraft spigot. I don't believe this is a spigot problem though, I believe this is a java problem. I have a method called setInjury() in my class that is supposed to make a copy of a list, remove an item from the copy and replace the list with the new one. The weird thing is, this works. For one item in particular though, it just refuses to remove it. It will remove other ones, but not this one. I checked casing and everything. Even the boolean from .remove says it has been removed, yet it just doesn't.

(iStore is a file configuration file while store is my class it's in)

It used to be in an if else statement, but the boolean inside the remove works just the same. The weirdest thing about all of this is it was literally working yesterday.

```
List<String> sevs = iStore.getStringList(uuid + "." + section);

for(String s : iStore.getStringList(uuid + "." + section)) {
    boolean isFracture = s.equals("Fracture") && injury.equals("Broken") ;

    if(s.equals(injury)) {
        continue;
    }

    sevs.add("Broken");
    sevs.remove(isFracture ? "Fracture" : "Intact");

    iStore.set(uuid + "." + section, sevs);
    store.saveStore();

}
```

My other more messy code that does the same thing, to prove that it should remove it:

```
    List<String> sevs = iStore.getStringList(uuid + "." + section);
    for(String s : iStore.getStringList(uuid + "." + section)) {
        if(sevs.contains(injury)) {
            return;
        }else if(injury.equals("Broken") && s.equals("Fracture")){
            sevs.add("Broken");
            sevs.remove("Fracture");

          Bukkit.getLogger().info(Boolean.toString(sevs.remove("Fracture"))); //returns true??
            iStore.set(uuid + "." + section, sevs);
            store.saveStore();
        }else{
            sevs.add(injury);
            sevs.remove("Intact");
            iStore.set(uuid + "." + section, sevs);
            store.saveStore();
        }
```

List before running code:

```
rlegstat: 
 - Cured 
 - Fracture 
//Desired result if injury is equal to broken: 
rlegstat: 
 - Cured 
 - Broken 
//Actual results 
rlegstat: 
 - Cured 
 - Fracture 
 - Broken
```

Comment: Please add your data set (values in iStore) and your wished result set

Comment: rlegstat:
  - Cured
  - Fracture

Result if injury is equal to broken:
rlegstat:
  - Cured
  - Broken
Actual results 
rlegstat:
  - Cured
  - Fracture
  - Broken

Comment: Does `iStore.getStringList` return a reference to the same list every time, or does it return a new copy of the list each time it's called?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow your exact logic (since you didn't give us a full method, for example it's unclear where `injury` is coming from), but it seems you don't need to loop at all. Simply using `.contains()`, `.add()` and `.remove()` should suffice:

```
private addInjury(String section, String injury) {
  String storeKey = uuid + "." + section;
  List<String> sevs = iStore.getStringList(storeKey);
  if (injury.equals("Broken")) {
    sevs.remove("Fracture"); // no need to check if it's in sev, if it isn't this will do nothing.
  } else {
    sevs.remove("Intact"); // depending on the desired logic, this could just go after the if outside of the else block.
  }
  if (!sevs.contains(injury)) {
    sevs.add(injury);
  }
  iStore.set(storeKey, sevs);
  store.saveStore();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid unpredictable behaviour and even a potential ConcurrentModificationException, instead of using enhanced for loop, use [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), which supports removing element while iterating over them.

Alternatively, you could use simple for loop and iterate backwards:

```
List<String> list;

for(int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(list.get(i).contains("bad")){
                list.remove(i);
        }
}
```